# Why does assign Eigen::Affine3f raise a segfault

Tags: c++, eigen

I have two classes. One base class and a inherited class.
In `header.h`

```
#include<Eigen/Dense>
...

class IClassA
{
public:
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
    Eigen::Affine3f matrixAffine;
    virtual void setmatrixAffine(const std::array<float, 6>& transform){};
};

class ClassA : public IClassA
{
public:
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
    Eigen::Affine3f matrixAffine;
    void setmatrixAffine(const std::array<float, 6>& transform) override;
};
```

In `function.cpp`

```
#include "header.h"

IClassA::IClassA(){};

ClassA::ClassA(){ // do something here };

void ClassA::setmatrixAffine(const std::array<float, 6>& transform){
    matrixAffine = pcl::getTransformation(transformIn[3], transformIn[4], transformIn[5], transformIn[0], transformIn[1], transformIn[2]);
}
```

in `main.cpp`

```
#include "header.h"

int main(){
    bool useDummy = true;
    
    std::shared_ptr<IClassA> classPtr;   // in the original program this ptr is shared between multiple class

    if (useDummy){
       classPtr = std::make_shared<IClassA>();
    } else {
       classPtr = std::make_shared<ClassA>();
    }
    
    std::array<float, 6> transform = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    classPtr->setmatrixAffine(transform);

}
```

and it kept raising `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` randomly when assign value to `matrixAffine`. Doesn't raise segfault everytime I run the function but sometimes it will. `pcl::getTransformation` seems to working fine. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you do `make_shared`, it seems that you are creating a shared_ptr of the `IClassA` interface rather than the `ClassA` derived class. Is this intentionally part of the example?

Comment: I might be missing something. The idea is that `IClassA` is dummy class. I have a master class that has `IClassA` as a class variable. I want to disable some functionality with a flag `useDummy`. eg. there is a visualizer that if I don't wan to plot stuff then it will call `IClassA` but if I do want to plot stuff then it will use `ClassA` which has actual implementation of plotting. Since `ClassA` is a child class `IClassA`, so I can only define `classPtr` as `IClassA` because `ClassA` is also a `IClassA`.

Comment: There is a chance that alignment is the issue if your compiler is too old. Try replacing ```make_shared``` with ```std::allocate_shared<ClassA>(Eigen::aligned_allocator<ClassA>{})``` See http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStlContainers.html https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared

Comment: Also, you define the ```matrixAffine``` attribute twice. ```ClassA``` will have two instances both with the same name, meaning that the one of the parent class will be masked when accessed through a ```ClassA``` pointer. The one in ```IClassA``` will remain uninitialized and cause your issues

Comment: Your code is not a [mre] (as it is, it won't even compile -- please read the link how to provide a one, then [edit] your question). Is using PCL required to reproduce the issue? If yes, add the `point-cloud-library` tag and say which version you are using, otherwise, remove it from your MRE.

Comment: Also, which compiler and flags and which platform are you using?

Comment: Thanks. I think `make_shared with std::allocate_shared<ClassA>(Eigen::aligned_allocator<ClassA>{})` works for me in the end. For `matrixAffine` i didn't mean to define twice.

Comment: You could compile (everything) with `-std=c++17` (or later).